# is there a way to get the specific text in an iterated create_text()?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
        def on_press_edit(e):
            print('test')
            title_get = note_canvas.itemcget(title, 'text')
            for cells in range(2, ea.max_row + 1):
                if title_get == ea['A' + str(cells)].value:
                    print(title_get)
        
        for added_notes in range(2, ea.max_row + 1):
            seperation = (added_notes * 90) - 120
            value = ea['A' + str(added_notes)].value
            cell_text = ea['B' + str(added_notes)].value
            text_display = cell_text[:20]
            note_canvas = Canvas(canvas, height=80, width=315, bg='#FBADB1')
            title = note_canvas.create_text(10, 22, text=value, anchor='w', font=('San Francisco', 14, 'bold'))
            note_canvas.create_text(10, 45, text=text_display + '...', anchor='w', font=('San Francisco', 10))
            note_canvas.bind('<Button-1>', on_press_edit)
            window = canvas.create_window(165, seperation, window=note_canvas)
        
            canvas.update_idletasks()
            canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
            vbar.set(0, 1)
```

> The title_get in on_press_edit() only returns the last data value in my database. I wanted to get the corresponding text from title = note_canvas.create_text(), is there a way to do it?

I already tried itemcget() function but it only returns the last data value in the database

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tag `"current"` with `itemcget` to get the text of the item directly under the cursor.

```
title_get = note_canvas.itemcget("current", 'text')
```

This is how the special tag `"current"` is defined in the canonical documentation:

"The tag **current** is managed automatically by Tk; it applies to the *current* item, which is the topmost item whose drawn area covers the position of the mouse cursor (different item types interpret this in varying ways; see the individual item type documentation for details). If the mouse is not in the canvas widget or is not over an item, then no item has the **current** tag."